# Salesforce Sandbox Org is not sending out emailtemplates

Tags: apex, email-template

I am currently working on an org where I am currently having trouble sending out email templates. In the send test for the email template, I have checked the sample send test when choosing to verify a user and the email I set to send a sample email to receives nothing. I have also tried using Apex to try sending the email template with no luck (for reference I used code similar to one found in this [article](https://hicglobalsolutions.com/blog/how-to-send-an-email-with-or-without-an-email-template-using-apex-in-salesforce/)).  I have tried updating the Access Level to "All email" in Deliverability and the Test Deliverability email does send to the selected email. Also the user email is a valid email.

Any ideas what could be the problem or what I could try?

Comment: 99% of the time if `Setup | Deliverability` is `All`, the email will send/deliver.  Check `Setup | Email Logs` to see if actually sent.

Comment: Hmm yes I figured that that would solve it as my search around provided that as the solution. I wonder if it's a problem with the org itself as doing an email log request keeps resulting in the following error: "We can't deliver your logs because of an error. Try searching again."